# Ethereum Miners and Gas - Analyzing Chain Data

Tags: blockchain, mining, chaindata

Currently looking at https://medium.com/google-cloud/how-to-query-balances-for-all-ethereum-addresses-in-bigquery-fb594e4034a7 and in the SQL Query to calculate address balances there is a part for  tranasction feed debits miners incur? How does that work? Miners are spending gas to mine?

```
-- transaction fees debits
select miner as address, sum(cast(receipt_gas_used as numeric) * cast(gas_price as numeric)) as value
from `bigquery-public-data.crypto_ethereum.transactions` as transactions
join `bigquery-public-data.crypto_ethereum.blocks` as blocks on blocks.number = transactions.block_number
group by blocks.miner
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a fee owed *to* the miner, rather than one they've incurred.

If you look at the final entry - `transaction fees credits` - it starts with `select from_address as address`, and as the sender of the transaction, the `from_address` is clearly going to be the one paying the transaction fee (with the miner therefore receiving it).

(In double-entry bookkeeping I'm pretty sure a debit of an *asset* to your balance sheet is actually noted as a balance increase. Someone who knows more about accounting can confirm... )

---

**Edit:**

https://www.investopedia.com/terms/d/double-entry.asp

*"For example, a debit increases asset accounts but decreases liability and equity accounts, which supports the general accounting equation of Assets = Liabilities + Equity."*

Answer (score 0):

The above section of the SQL query represents transaction fees that are incurred by senders and that are delivered to miners.